# Adding icon to Internet Explorer addon

Tags: internet-explorer-11, bho

I am trying to add an icon to my Internet Explorer addon, here is my registry:
[image]

And here is the result in browser:

[image]

> But I don't see the icon `mm.ico`, what I'm missing?

[Related](https://github.com/SwatiSwa/IE-AddOns)

Comment: I tried to refer the steps mentioned in the Github page and I created the BHO and registry keys. I also saw similar behavior. The icon is not displaying. See here. https://imgur.com/a/MVrqV00 You can notice that if you check in the manage Add-ons window. You can see the icon there. so the issue is related to HotIcon value. I will try to search further and if I get any helpful information then I will try to inform you.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Ok, I will wait for an asnwer